# How can i convert this obsucured decrypt python code in dart?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

i am trying to get obscured email that was obscured by firewall.
i found the solution in python but i don't know to do this in dart or flutter.
here is the python code

```
    r = int(encodedString[:2],16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(encodedString[i:i+2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(2, len(encodedString), 2)])
    return email

print cfDecodeEmail('543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39') # usage
```

Comment: Do you see what this does?  It takes the first byte (`54`) as a hex value,. and exclusive-ors that with each of the other bytes to produce a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Python, `encodedString[:2]`/`encodedString[i:i+2]` extract two characters from `encodedString`.  The Dart equivalent (assuming ASCII characters) would be `encodedString.substring(0, 2)` and `encodedString(i, i + 2)` respectively.
- The equivalent of Python's `''.join(list)` in Dart is `list.join()`.
- The equivalent of a Python's list comprehensions (`[i for i in items]`) in Dart is collection-`for`: `[for (var i in items) i]`.
- The equivalent of Python's `for i in range(2, len(encodedString), 2)` in Dart is to use a basic `for` loop with a start, condition, and increment: `for (var i = 2; i < encodedString.length; i += 2)`.
- In Python, `int(string, 16)` parses `string` as a hexadecimal number.  In Dart, use `int.parse(string, radix: 16)`.
- In Python, `chr(integer)` creates a string from the specified code point.  The equivalent in Dart is `String.fromCharCode(integer)`.

Putting it all together:

```dart
String cfDecodeEmail(String encodedString) {
  var r = int.parse(encodedString.substring(0, 2), radix: 16);
  var email = [
    for (var i = 2; i < encodedString.length; i += 2)
      String.fromCharCode(
        int.parse(encodedString.substring(i, i + 2), radix: 16) ^ r,
      )
  ].join();
  return email;
}

void main() {
  // Prints: me@usamaejaz.com
  print(cfDecodeEmail('543931142127353935313e352e7a373b39'));
}
```